# IPWEditor with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, tinymce

I am trying to write a module with IPWEditor with jQuery.

The main task is to be able to drag a div around and the div will be editable with Tinymce when a user double clicking on the div, another thing is there is a button that add a new div when clicking on the button.

Where is the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ipweditor-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.text').live('click', function() {
            $(this).draggable( {containment: 'parent'});
        });

        var ed = new tinymce.Editor('content', {
            mode: "exact",
            theme: "advanced",
            plugins: "emotions,table",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing: true,
            theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,sup,sub,charmap,fontselect,fontsizeselect,forecolor,backcolor,",
            theme_advanced_buttons2: "copy,paste,undo,redo,|,hr,blockquote,bullist,numlist,outdent,indent,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,image,emotions,",
            theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
            table_default_cellspacing: 0,
            table_default_border: 1,
            remove_linebreaks : false
        });

        $('.test').live('dblclick',function(){
            $(this).editable({
                tooltip : "",
                indicator : 'Saving...',
                type: 'wysiwyg',
                editor: ed,
                submit:'save',
                cancel:'cancel'
            });
        }); 

    }); 

    function displaymessage()
    {
        $(".boxContainer").append("<div class='text test' style='width: 280px' onClick='$(this).addClass(&#39;selectedBorder&#39;)' onmouseout='$(this).removeClass(&#39;selectedBorder&#39;)'> Click me! I am editable and WYSIWYG!!!</div>");
    }
</script>
<style>
    p {margin:0; padding: 0;}
    .text {cursor:pointer; line-height: 100%; border: 1px dotted transparent;}
    .selectedBorder {border: 1px dotted black;}
</style>


</head>
<body>    
<div class="boxContainer" style="border: solid thin gray; width: 1000px; height: 500px">
    <div class="text test" style="width: 280px" onClick="$(this).addClass('selectedBorder')" onmouseout="$(this).removeClass('selectedBorder')">
        <b> Click me! I am editable and WYSIWYG!!!</b>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="newBox" onclick="displaymessage();">Add new box</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Now to the main problem, when I click on the "Add new box" button, a new div appear. The div is draggable and when I double click on the new div, the div is editable but when I try to click on the save button, Nothing happens.

Can anyone give me a hint or help me.

Thank you very much in advance.

Best Regards / Johnny

Answer (score 0):

The save button will submit the form in which the element lies for which you init the editor. But i cannot see any form in your html!!! The save button is only a triggger to submit the editor content to a script where it can be stored to a db.

Comment: I don't want to stored to a db yet.

My first test with the div 

<div class="text test" style="width: 280px" onClick="$(this).addClass('selectedBorder')" onmouseout="$(this).removeClass('selectedBorder')">
        <b> Click me! I am editable and WYSIWYG!!!</b>
    </div>


works very well, I can edit and stored the changes. But when I add a new div with a button. The new div don't save when I click on the save button.

Comment: it might be helpfull if you describe exactly what you do with your divs. where do you store what and how?

Comment: I maybe know what's the problem is now. The DOM have already loaded, that is why my first div can save and edit. The second div when I click on add new box is after the DOM is loaded. That is why I can't serializer the new div. It got a "t.serializer is undefined" problem. Is there a way to reload dom?

Comment: you may use: window.location.href=window.location.href;